# Animated GIF to video with ffmpeg - wrong timing

Tags: ffmpeg, animated-gif

I'm trying to convert an animated GIF to video with **ffmpeg**, but there's a strange problem: the time delays of each frame seem to be off by one frame.
For example, if the frame #1 is supposed to be shown for 2000 ms and the frames from #2 to #10 are supposed to be shown for 100 ms each, in the resulting video it immediately skips to the frame #2 which is shown for 2000 ms instead :P

Is this some kind of a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my command line:

```
ffmpeg –i Mnozenie_anim_deop.gif Mnozenie_anim.mp4
```

(Aside: why doesn't the "-" show up in code blocks unless I replace it with "–"?)

so nothing extraordinary, just the defaults. (Unless this is the root of the problem? Maybe my defaults are bad, and I need to specify some magic options?)

This problem seems to appear for any video formats except MKV, and when I play these files in **mplayer**, they all behave that way except MKV.

But when I open them in **kdenlive** (a non-linear video editing program), the problem appears in all of them, including MKV (which is strange, because it plays back just fine in **mplayer** :q ).

I tried converting the same exact file with this online converter here:
https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4
and there is no problem with its output – it plays back fine both in **mplayer** and when imported to **kdenlive**, so I guess they must have been using some magic command line options that I'm missing.

Any ideas what can be wrong and how to track down the culprit?

**Edit:**  Here's a sample animated GIF file I'm trying to convert:
http://nauka.mistu.info/Matematyka/Algebra/Szeregi/Mnozenie_anim.gif
and the MP4 file that I generated from it which demonstrates this problem:
http://sasq.comyr.com/Stuff/Mnozenie_anim.mp4
As you can see, the fade in starts prematurely but stops for a couple of seconds instead of waiting for a couple of seconds BEFORE the fade in begins.

Comment: Can you share the GIF?

Comment: Sure thing. I added tie link above in another edit.

Comment: Works fine here with your command. https://www.sendspace.com/file/nyf5su  Check with a recent ffmpeg build.

Comment: Hmm... my version of **ffmpeg** is 2.2.14 from May 2015. Could it be the cause? I'll try with some more recent version later and let you know...

Comment: OK looks like it really works fine in more recent version of **ffmpeg**. The problem was only with my older version, seems like a bug then.